# How to implement Sliding tabs in ionic v1?

Tags: ionic-framework, material-design, hybrid-mobile-app, slidingmenu

[image: Sliding tabs]
I am new in hybrid app development and I want to implement sliding Tabs in ionic v1. I searched for this topic on google but all gives code solution in ionic 2. And I am working on Ionic v1. Is it possible to implement sliding tab like material design in ionic v1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have solve this issue,
> It can difficult to create slide tab in ionic 1
>   
> but I have long research after i will found one code of slide tab
>  follow this link to full code of [sliding tab](http://play.ionic.io/app/e77390f97951)

Comment: Above link not available @vishal can you please provide some other link

Comment: Hi Sharad Kale, Sorry for link not longer exist. Ionic 1 have not support for scrolling tab But now you can use ionic 3 for better usage https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157896/ionic-horizontal-scroll-tab-for-categories