# How to achieve Horizontal Scrolling in categories like in google play store In Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, horizontal-scrolling, ionic3

i am able to get horizontal scrolling with `<io-scroll>` but scrolling is done with bottom scrolling bar and my requirement is to scroll category on swipe in same as we see in google play store.
i was trying to achieve this with [link](https://github.com/drewrygh/ionic-ion-horizontal-scroll-cards) but it doesn't work for me and i found similar question about scrolling but it does with `<ion-scroll>`

[image: this i want in ionic 2]

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157896/ionic-scroll-programmatically/45158789#45158789). Not sure if that's exactly what you were looking for, but it may be styled to look like a tab...

Comment: @sebaferreras it was really awesome and lot's of thankyou for this answer. i was trying to achieve this from last 6 days. Thank you so much

Comment: Really? So glad to hear that it helped :) I'll mark this question as duplicate of that one, just to make it easier for other SO users to find it.