# Scroll inside scroll not working in ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

hello friends i want to develop scroll in scroll in vertical and horizontal both manner means main scroll is vertical and inside that horizontal block will be there my code is as below

```
page-horizontal {
.inner{
 width: 2000px;
 height: 100%;

 ion-card{
   display: table-cell;
   border: solid 1px #ccc;
  }

}

.outer{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

 ion-card{
   display: inline-block;
   border: solid 1px #ccc;
    }

  }

}
```

my html file

```
<ion-content>
 <ion-scroll scrollY="true" style="width:100%; height: 100%">
   <div class="outer">
  <ion-card *ngFor="let item of mMainProductBlocks">
    <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
    <ion-scroll scrollX="true" style="width:100%; height: 200px">
      <div class="inner">
        <ion-card *ngFor="let subitem of item.data">
          <img src='{{subitem.image}}'>
        </ion-card>
      </div>
      </ion-scroll>

    </ion-card>
     </div>

   </ion-scroll>

</ion-content>
```

when i run above code i get below output refer SS

[image: image output]

In above screenshots one vertical scroll which is block with title like "Latesst for you, Rebook Footwear ..etc" and inside that block which is horizontal but it is not come in horizontal manner so any idea how can i solve this?

Comment: Why don't you use `ion-slide` here?

Comment: Swapnil Patwa : i m  new in ionic so i post question and i need suggestion for that how i can achieve if you know than post your suggestion so i can try with that

Comment: have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157896/ionic-horizontal-scroll-tab-for-categories

Comment: You will need to modify this according to your design.

Comment: Swapnil Patwa : thanks for your suggestions it is working