# how make contents swiper with the bar?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, swiper.js

I need to make my content able to switch to another slide by swiping without navigating, and effect to swiper bar in the top, I found [Swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/), but how I can make it like this?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but just in case, please take a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157896/ionic-horizontal-scroll-tab-for-categories/45158789#45158789)**