# Ionic horizontal scroll bar

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I refer to the answer from [Ionic - Horizontal scroll tab for Categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157896/ionic-horizontal-scroll-tab-for-categories/45158789#45158789).

Could anyone tell me what should be included in the category.model?

Answer (score 0):

`category.model` is the file which will have the `CategoryModel` interface.

it should have:

```
export interface CategoryModel {
  id: number,
  name: string
  // add more things here based on your need
}
```

Read more about interfaces here: [typescript interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)